An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (732A03A7)
when I am trying to do 'Verify your Play Console developer account' and I get to 'How Google contacts you', I get that error pop up at bottom left and I cannot verify the ph number listed there. The process cannot move forward.
There seems to be a lot of "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (Error Code)" and where does google give information on that "Error Code" ?

Well, I have refreshed the play.google.com/console/developer page and restart the process and the error goes away.
